# In Dying Light, what do the tiny white bouncing arrows indicate in the mini-map?

Tags: dying-light

Every so often, I see tiny white arrows in the mini-map that bounce up and down a little.  I'm almost done with the game and never did figure out what they represent.  At first I thought they might indicate a horde, because they usually show up in a group of four or five arrows, but that doesn't seem to be it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrows are used to indicate difference in height between character and object.

E.g. look on picture below. This arrows indicate that traps are lower than character.
[image]

And here white arrows show, that shop, bad etc are on higher floor.
[image]

If those are not arrows you mean, please, provide screenshot.

Comment: I'd add that they indicate height when they are in sight of your mini map but when they're off the map a bit such as the right most trap in the first screen shot it's showing you the direction of a friendly/usable thing on the map. (There is a shop nearby in X direction basically)